# How do I insert data in a table, using with open?

Tags: python, mariadb

Here is my code:

```
with open(r"filename.csv", 'r') as file:
  csvreader = csv.reader(file)
  for row in csvreader:
    print(row)
```

Instead of print(row) I want to write each line of data the forloop is iterating through to a table in MariaDB. Is it possible to do that without using "INSERT INTO table VALUES x", I want to write each line being read to the empty table I have. This table has 3,000,000 records so I can't list out every one of them..

Comment: If you want to instert row-by-row then `INSERT` is your only option. If you're importing a large CSV file then you should look at `LOAD DATA INFILE` to load the entire file directly into the table. See the [reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html)

Comment: MariaDB is not MySQL. I removed the mysql tag from this question. MariaDB started as a fork of MySQL in 2010, but both products continue to change since then. You shouldn't think of them as compatible products anymore, and you should use the documentation for the product you are using: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/load-data-infile/

Comment: I can't use load data infile because of security issues

Comment: can I use "INSERT" but select all the columns and rows?

Comment: @frustrated_gerbil What security issues? MariaDB imposes some basic requirements for you to use LOAD DATA INFILE, but these are easily addressed. Or is there some other issue we should know about?

Comment: i dont know my co workers dont want me using that because of security issues, they won't say much else. i have to find a standardized way of importing these tables anyway so i cant manually do it

Comment: Loading data row by row is going to take much longer than `LOAD DATA INFILE`. If you have to do this every week, or even every month, you're going to waste a great deal of time. I'd be asking my co-workers to explain the security issues, then look to address them, rather than just twiddling my thumbs for hours each week while the system `INSERT`s 3 million records.

Comment: How many bytes is the CSV file?

Comment: the csv file is 96,000 KB

Answer (score 0):

If the columns in the CSV file are in the same order as the table, you can use a simple `INSERT` query that omits the list of column names.

You can use `executemany()` to insert many rows at a time to make it more efficient.

```
with open(r"filename.csv", 'r') as file:
    csvreader = csv.reader(file)
    rows = list(csvreader)

placeholders = ','.join(['%s'] * len(rows[0]))
cursor.executemany(f"INSERT INTO yourTable VALUES ({placeholders})", rows)
```

Comment: i tried this and it said : "TypeError: not enough arguments for format string"

Comment: Make sure all the rows of the file have the same number of fields.

Comment: ok now it's saying: TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

I dont think my data types match

Comment: That still seems like a mismatch in the number of fields. The first error will happen for a line with fewer fields than the first line, the second will happen if there are more fields.

Comment: The `placeholders` variable gets the number of columns from the first line of the CSV.

Comment: i compared the column count in the csv and database and they match so im not sure why its saying that

Comment: What do you see if you do `print(set(map(len, rows)))`?